# How to toggle a nested array in svelte

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, toggle, svelte, nested-lists

Im working in svelte and i have an array
Eg: array=[{name:'aa',status1:true, status2:false, status3: false}]
(Asume thats between script tags)

Now in the actual html part
How do you toggle each one of the statuses individually using a single toggle function

I tried toggle(task1.status1)
But its not working as expected

Comment: Please add more details, like how do you show the array ? what is `task1` ? what do you mean with toggle (toggle() is not a standard function)